# Rabbitmq retrieve multiple messages using single synchronous call

Tags: rabbitmq, synchronous

Is there a way to receive multiple message using a single synchronous call ?

When I know that there are N messages( N could be a small value less than 10) in the queue, then I should be able to do something like channel.basic_get(String queue, boolean autoAck , int numberofMsg ). I don't want to make multiple requests to the server .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RabbitMQ's `basic.get` doesn't support multiple messages unfortunately [as seen in the docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#basic.get). The preferred method to retrieve multiple messages is to use [basic.consume](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#basic.consume) which will push the messages to the client avoiding multiple round trips. `acks` are asynchronous so your client won't be waiting for the server to respond. `basic.consume` also has the benefit of allowing RabbitMQ to redeliver the message if the client disconnects, something that `basic.get` cannot do. This can be turned off as well setting `no-ack` to `true`.

Setting `basic.qos` `prefetch-count` will set the number of messages to push to the client at any time. If there isn't a message waiting on the client side (which would return immediately) client libraries tend to block with an optional timeout.

Comment: This is not an answer to what was asked. There are scenarios (for example due to security concerns) where connections cannot be triggered from the message broker but only from the secure zone to the less secure zone. Being so, this is still missing an answer to what was asked.

Comment: There may have been changes to AMQP or RabbitMQ that allow a synchronous call to get multiple messages in the intervening years. Connections for RabbitMQ are from client -> Rabbit. The publishing of messages happens over this existing connection. Usage of `basic.get` or `basic.consume` doesn't change how the connection is established.

Comment: This is about consuming messages not publishing. Does that means that a connection is established by the consumer and then stays open in order for RabbitMQ callbacks work? This may not be a possibility in some scenarios as well with limiting firewall rules.. In that sense the usage of age of basic.get or basic.consume indeed change how the connection is handled.

Comment: The client makes the connection whether consuming or publishing, regardless of the commands that are used over the connection. The callbacks are handled by client libraries as a result of AMQP messages over that connection.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `QueueingConsumer` implementation of `Consumer` interface which allows you to retrieve several messages in a single request.

```
 QueueingConsumer queueingConsumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
 channel.basicConsume(plugin.getQueueName(), false, queueingConsumer);

 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = queueingConsumer.nextDelivery(100);//read timeout in ms
    if(delivery == null){
      break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Nowadays it is a deprecated solution. https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.4.1/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.4.1/com/rabbitmq/client/QueueingConsumer.html

Answer (score 2):

Not an elegant solution and does not solve making multiple calls but you can use the MessageCount method. For example:

```
  bool noAck = false;
  var messageCount = channel.MessageCount("hello");
  BasicGetResult result = null;
  if (messageCount == 0)
  {
      // No messages available
  }
  else
  {
      while (messageCount > 0)
      {
          result = channel.BasicGet("hello", noAck);
          var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Body);
          //process message .....
          messageCount = channel.MessageCount("hello");
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

First declare instance of QueueingBasicConsumer() wich wraps the model.
From the model execute model.BasicConsume(QueueName, false, consumer)
Then implement a loop that will loop around messages from the queue which will then processing
Next line - consumer.Queue.Dequeue() method - waiting for the message to be received from the queue.
Then convert byte array to a string and display it.
Model.BasicAck() - release message from the queue to receive next message
And then on the server side can start waiting for the next message to come through:

```
  public string GetMessagesByQueue(string QueueName)
    {
        var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(_model);
        _model.BasicConsume(QueueName, false, consumer);

        string message = string.Empty;

        while (Enabled)
        {
            //Get next message
            var deliveryArgs = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();

            //Serialize message
             message = Encoding.Default.GetString(deliveryArgs.Body);
                _model.BasicAck(deliveryArgs.DeliveryTag, false);
        }
        return message;
    }
```